# how to reduce the spacing between the columns? HIGHCHARTS

Tags: highcharts, column-chart

I want to reduce the distance between the columns.
I was trying : plot Options column: pointPadding , border Width , pointWidth

Code:

```
  `https://jsfiddle.net/x1m0et85/2/`
```

I need something like the first picture

[image]

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reduce this distance by setting `groupPadding`.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.groupPadding

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6v8bdky4/